# How can I display or view multiple checkbox WHERE condition in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need help.I can't apply **WHERE** Condition clause in my Multiple selected checkbox value.like If i select 'accounitng' or 'php' then i want here use a condition like **WHERE** **("skill", "php")** here, skill table field name and php checkbox selected value.If i select a category 'PHP' so all 'PHP' related data only show.Checkbox selected value save into databse with ' , ' comma separated. like *`php,java,accounting,sql`*

For save data i used for Model:

```
public function saveInstituteOfferCourse($data = array()) {
        if ($this->db->insert('tbl_course_offred', $data)) {
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
```

for controller i use:

```
public function saveCourses() {
        $data = array();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('skill', 'skill', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            /* @var $skill user_admin_controller */
            $skill = implode(',', $this->input->post('skill'));
            $data['skill'] = $skill;
            $data['user_id'] = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
            $this->user_admin_model->saveInstituteOfferCourse($data);
            redirect("user_admin_controller/userAdminPanel");
        }
    }
```

My workflow likes:

First: user select many skills using multiple checkbox and save selected data into DB table.

Second: if anyone click on category on fronted page like php or java then only php or java related data information/list show.

How can i do this please help me or suggest me for best.if possible provide me source code in codeignitor.

My applying code have a look,

Model,

```
public function selectaccoutingins() {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->select('skill');
        $this->db->from('tbl_user_reg, tbl_course_offred');
        $this->db->where('skill', "php");
        // here, i use two table 1 for information collect and other for category match condition value show.

        $query_result = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query_result->result();
        $result = explode(",", $query_result->result);
        return $result;

    }
```

Controller,

```
function accounting_ins_list() {
        $data = array();
        $data['result'] = $this->welcome_model->selectaccoutingins();
        $data['catepage_list'] = $this->load->view('accounting_ins_list', $data, true);
        $this->load->view('hmcate_select_page', $data);
    }
```

view,

```
               <tbody>
                    <?php

                    if($result) {
                    foreach ($result as $aresult) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $aresult->institute_name;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $aresult->contact_person; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $aresult->institute_address1;?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } 

                    }   ?>
                </tbody>
```

here i want to show only **PHP related** information list.Please help how can i solve this.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

you mean, if you check php and accounting, it will appear also to your view.?
And also you have problem in selecting data from two table?

you can visit on this site in query data - http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

I have an example query here.

```
      $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM logsTrans l,transType t 
                                WHERE l.transno = t.transno
                                AND t.transType = '$cat'                                    
                                AND date(l.transDate) >= '$dateF' 
                                AND date(l.transDate) <= '$dateT'");

            return $query->result();
```

Can i see the table and data yo uwant to get..? best regards...